# How to select nodes by class in cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

**CYTOSCAPE.JS**

I can't manage to apply styles to a class defined in node-data (`clLevel0`). I wrote a function to work around the problem.  So, the function also explains what i want to do,  in a much simpler way that is ;-)

```
function setNodesClassStyles(cy, clas, styleobject)
 {
   var all = cy.nodes();
   for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
       the_node = all[i];
       all_classes = the_node.data().classes;
       //alert(all_classes);
       if (all_classes != undefined) {
           all_classes = all_classes.split(' ');
           for (i = 0; i < all_classes.length; i++) {
               alert(all_classes[i]);
               if (clas == all_classes[i]) {
                   the_node.style(styleobject)
               }

           }
       }
   }
 };
setNodesClassStyles(cy, "clLevel0", {'background-color':'#00E'});
```

I tried this (not working):

```
{
  selector: ".clLevel0",
  style: {
    'background-color': '#EAA',
  }
},
```

What's the right way to apply styles on a node with a class 'clas'?
More code:

```
    var cy = cytoscape({

      container: document.getElementById('cy'), // container to render in

      elements: [ // list of graph elements to start with
      // LEVEL 0 NODE
        { // node 
          data: { id: 'me', name: 'Dirk\n@dickschrauwen', classes: 'clLevel0 clRoot', weight: 10000},

          "position": {
           "x": 600,
           "y": 400 },

        },

     // LEVEL 1 NODES
        {
          data: { id: 'skills', name: 'Skills',  }
        },  
        {
          data: { id: 'education', name: 'School' }
        },
        {
          data: { id: 'work', name: 'Jobs\nProjects' }
        },
        { 
          data: { id: 'passion', name: 'Passions' }
        },

// ....
  style: [
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'height': 40,
        'width':  40,
        //'height': 20,
        //'width':  20,
        'background-color': '#EE0',
// ....

    {
      selector: ".clLevel0",
      style: {
        'background-color': '#EAA',
      }
    },

  ],
//...
```

Comment: (1) If your nodes have multiple overlapping style properties (e.g. background in nodes, .clLevel0, ..) only the last defined property gets applied

(2) classes are to be accessed through node.addClass('..'), .removeClass('..'), .hasClass('..'), ..

(3) .style(stylesheet) doesn't work on nodes, but on the core cytoscape instance

Comment: Thanx Tom, the problem was in (WRONG)``data: { id: 'me', name: 'Dirk', classes: 'clLevel0', weight: 10000}`` RIGHT: ``data: { id: 'me', name: 'Dirk'}, classes: 'clLevel0', weight: 10000``

Answer (score 3):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    elements: {
       nodes: [
          { data: { id: 'n', label: 'Olo' } },
          { data: { id: 'c'}, classes: 'className'}
    ]}
   });
  cy.style.fromJson([
      {
         selector: 'node',
         style: {
             'color': 'red'
         }
       },{
         selector: '.className',
         style: {
             'label': 'this has a class',
             'color': 'blue'
        }
      }
   ])
});
```